# Why is this result more accurate than another result by equivalent functions

Tags: python, floating-point, precision

I have the following question, why is `myf(x)` giving less accurate results than `myf2(x)`. Here is my python code:

```
from math import e, log

def Q1():
    n = 15
    for i in range(1, n):
        #print(myf(10**(-i)))
        #print(myf2(10**(-i)))
    return

def myf(x):
    return ((e**x - 1)/x)

def myf2(x):
    return ((e**x - 1)/(log(e**x)))
```

Here is the output for myf(x):

```
1.0517091807564771
1.005016708416795
1.0005001667083846
1.000050001667141
1.000005000006965
1.0000004999621837
1.0000000494336803
0.999999993922529
1.000000082740371
1.000000082740371
1.000000082740371
1.000088900582341
0.9992007221626409
0.9992007221626409
```

myf2(x):

```
1.0517091807564762
1.0050167084168058
1.0005001667083415
1.0000500016667082
1.0000050000166667
1.0000005000001666
1.0000000500000017
1.000000005
1.0000000005
1.00000000005
1.000000000005
1.0000000000005
1.00000000000005
1.000000000000005
```

I believe it has something to do with the floating point number system in python in combination with my machine. The natural log of euler's number produces a number with more digits of precision than its equivalent number x as an integer.

Comment: Your output does not match the code you have posted. Post a [mre].

Comment: You might want to print the result of `n == log(e**n))` for that range.

Comment: Expand `e**(10**(-x))` respectively `log(e**(10**(-x)))` into taylor series or use wolfram alpha. Then you see the first two terms just deviate by a factor of `e` in both cases. Therefore (neglecting higher order terms), nominator and denominator cancel out in this approximation which isn't the case when using `x` in the denominator. I believe this is the reason as neither `1/(10**(-x))` vs. `1/log(exp(10**(-x)))` nor `exp(10**(-x))/(10**(-x))` `exp(10**(-x))/log(exp(10**(-x)))` behaved the same way round.

Comment: @EOF: I got exactly the same output using python 3.6.9.

Comment: The trick used in `myf2()` is due to William Kahan. It is demonstrated and explained in Nicholas J. Higham, "Accuracy and Stability of Numerical Algorithms, Second Edition", SIAM 2002. Section 1.14.1 (pp. 19-21). The underlying principle is cancellation of rounding errors.

Comment: The original reference for Kahan's trick is: W. Kahan, "Interval arithmetic options in the proposed IEEE floating point arithmetic standard". In: Karl L. E. Nickel (e.d), *Interval Mathematics 1980*, New York: Academic Press 1980, pp. 99-128. Google scan of the relevant page: [page 110](https://books.google.com/books?id=sLvSBQAAQBAJ&lpg=PP1&pg=PA110#v=onepage&q=110&f=false). Hm, the direct link doesn't seem to work. Try going to page 75 and then clicking "page forward" until you get to page 110.

Comment: To compute (exp(x)-1)/x more accurately use numpy.exp1  in expm1(x)/x. Once x is small enough that exp(x) == 1 (around 1e-16) your f2 will give -nan while expm1(x)/x gives 1.0

Comment: @dmuir: No need for NumPy here; Python has `math.expm1`. (Nothing _wrong_ with using NumPy for this if it's already in your environment, but it's not necessary.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's start with the difference between `x` and `log(exp(x))`, because the rest of the computation is the same.

```py
>>> for i in range(10):
...     x = 10**-i
...     y = exp(x)
...     print(x, log(y))
... 
1 1.0
0.1 0.10000000000000007
0.01 0.009999999999999893
0.001 0.001000000000000043
0.0001 0.00010000000000004326
9.999999999999999e-06 9.999999999902983e-06
1e-06 9.99999999962017e-07
1e-07 9.999999994336786e-08
1e-08 9.999999889225291e-09
1e-09 1.000000082240371e-09
```

If you look closely, you might notice that there are errors creeping in.
When  = 0, there's no error.
When  = 1, it prints `0.1` for  and `0.10000000000000007` for `log(y)`, which is wrong only after 16 digits.
By the time  = 9, `log(y)` is wrong in half the digits from log().

Since we know what the true answer is (), we can easily compute what the relative error of the approximation is:

```py
>>> for i in range(10):
...     x = 10**-i
...     y = exp(x)
...     z = log(y)
...     print(i, abs((x - z)/z))
... 
0 0.0
1 6.938893903907223e-16
2 1.0755285551056319e-14
3 4.293440603042413e-14
4 4.325966668215291e-13
5 9.701576564765975e-12
6 3.798286318045685e-11
7 5.663213319457187e-10
8 1.1077471033430869e-08
9 8.224036409872509e-08
```

Each step loses us about a digit of accuracy!
Why?

Each of the operations `10**-i`, `exp(x)`, and `log(y)` only introduces a tiny relative error into the result, less than 10<sup>−15</sup>.

Suppose `exp(x)` introduces a relative error of , returning the number ⋅(1 + ) instead of  (which, after all, is a transcendental number that can't be represented by a finite string of digits).
We know that || < 10<sup>−15</sup>, but what happens when we then try to compute log(⋅(1 + )) as an approximation to log() = ?

We might hope to get ⋅(1 + ) where  is very small.
But log(⋅(1 + )) = log() + log(1 + ) =  + log(1 + ) = ⋅(1 + log(1 + )/), so  = log(1 + )/.
And even if  is small,  ≈ 10<sup>−</sup> gets closer and closer to zero as  increases, so the error log(1 + )/ ≈ / can get worse and worse as  increases because 1/ → ∞.

**We say that the logarithm function is *ill-conditioned* near 1: if you evaluate it at an approximation to an input near 1, it can turn a very small input error into an arbitrarily large output error.**  In fact, you can only go a few more steps before `exp(x)` is rounded to 1 and so `log(y)` returns zero exactly.

This is not because of anything in particular about floating-point—any kind of approximation would have the same effect with log!
The condition number of a function is a property of the mathematical function itself, not of the floating-point arithmetic system.
If the inputs came from physical measurements, you could run into the same problem.

---

This is related to why the functions `expm1` and `log1p` exist.
Although the function log() is ill-conditioned near 1, the function log(1 + ) is not, so `log1p(y)` computes it more accurately than evaluating it `log(1 + y)` can.
Similarly, the subtraction in `exp(x) - 1` is subject to [catastrophic cancellation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catastrophic_cancellation) when  ≈ 1, so `expm1(x)` computes  − 1 more accurately than evaluating `exp(x) - 1` can.

`expm1` and `log1p` are not the same functions as `exp` and `log`, of course, but sometimes you can rewrite subexpressions in terms of them to avoid ill-conditioned domains.
In this case, for example, if you rewrite log() as log(1 + [ − 1]), and use `expm1` and `log1p` to compute it, the round-trip is often computed exactly:

```py
>>> for i in range(10):
...     x = 10**-i
...     y = expm1(x)
...     z = log1p(y)
...     print(i, x, z, abs((x - z)/z))
... 
0 1 1.0 0.0
1 0.1 0.1 0.0
2 0.01 0.01 0.0
3 0.001 0.001 0.0
4 0.0001 0.0001 0.0
5 9.999999999999999e-06 9.999999999999999e-06 0.0
6 1e-06 1e-06 0.0
7 1e-07 1e-07 0.0
8 1e-08 1e-08 0.0
9 1e-09 1e-09 0.0
```

**For similar reasons, you might want to rewrite `(exp(x) - 1)/x` as `expm1(x)/x`.**
If you don't, then when `exp(x)` returns ⋅(1 + ) rather than , you will end up with (⋅(1 + ) − 1)/ = ( − 1 + )/ = ( − 1)⋅[1 + /( − 1)]/, which again may blow up because the error is /( − 1) ≈ /.

---

**However, it is *not* simply luck that the second definition seems to produce the correct results!**
This happens because the compounded errors—/ from `exp(x) - 1` in the numerator, / from `log(exp(x))` in the denominator—cancel each other out.
The first definition computes the numerator badly and the denominator accurately, but the second definition computes them both *about equally badly*!

In particular, when  ≈ 0, we have

log(⋅(1 + )) =  + log(1 + ) ≈  +

and

⋅(1 + ) − 1 =  +  − 1 ≈ 1 +  +  − 1 =  + .

Note that  is the *same* in both cases, because it's the error of using `exp(x)` to approximate .

You can test this experimentally by comparing against `expm1(x)/x` (which is an expression guaranteed to have low relative error, since division never makes errors much worse):

```py
>>> for i in range(10):
...     x = 10**-i
...     u = (exp(x) - 1)/log(exp(x))
...     v = expm1(x)/x
...     print(u, v, abs((u - v)/v))
... 
1.718281828459045 1.718281828459045 0.0
1.0517091807564762 1.0517091807564762 0.0
1.0050167084168058 1.0050167084168058 0.0
1.0005001667083415 1.0005001667083417 2.2193360112628554e-16
1.0000500016667082 1.0000500016667084 2.220335028798222e-16
1.0000050000166667 1.0000050000166667 0.0
1.0000005000001666 1.0000005000001666 0.0
1.0000000500000017 1.0000000500000017 0.0
1.000000005 1.0000000050000002 2.2204460381480824e-16
1.0000000005 1.0000000005 0.0
```

This approximation  +  to the numerator and the denominator is best for  closest to zero and worst for  farthest from zero—but as  gets farther from zero, the error magnification in `exp(x) - 1` (from catastrophic cancellation) and in `log(exp(x))` (from ill-conditioning of logarithm near 1) both diminish anyway, so the answer remains accurate.

---

However, the benign cancellation in the second definition only works until  is so close to zero that `exp(x)` is simply rounded to 1—at that point, `exp(x) - 1` and `log(exp(x))` both give zero and will end up trying to compute 0/0 which yields NaN and a floating-point exception.

**So you should use `expm1(x)/x` in practice, but it is a happy accident that *outside* the edge case where `exp(x)` is 1, two wrongs make a right in `(exp(x) - 1)/log(exp(x))` giving good accuracy even as `(exp(x) - 1)/x` and (for similar reasons) `expm1(x)/log(exp(x))` both give bad accuracy.**

Answer (score 0):

> Why is this result more accurate than another result by equivalent functions

Bad luck.  Neither function is reliable pass about `(17-n)/2` digits.

Difference in results relies on common implementations of `exp` and `log`, yet not language specified.

---

For a given `x` as a negative `n` power of 10, the extended math result is `1.(n zeroes)5(n-1 zeros)166666....`

With `exp(x) - 1`, both functions lose about half of their significance as `n` becomes greater due to severe calculation of `exp(small_value)` and `1`.

`exp(x)-1` retains a semblance of the math value as long of the typical float with it typical 17-ish digits of precision.

When `n` == `7`, `exp(x) = 1.00000010000000494...` and `exp(x)-1` is `1.0000000494...e-07`.

`n = 8`: the wheels fell off.

When `n` == `8`, `exp(x) = 1.00000000999999994...` and `exp(x)-1` is `9.99999993922529029...e-09`.

`9.99999993922529029...e-09` is not near enough to `1.000000005...e-08`.

At that point, both functions suffer a loss of precision in the `1.00000000x` place.

---

Let `n` go up to 16 or so and then it all breaks down

Comment: @njuffa True that other code and/or other  compliers (with various optimization settings) will have different results.  The key is that `e**x - 1` is prone to severe precision loss when `x` is small.

Comment: @njuffa Interesting. Would you say Python specifies `log(e**x)` to perform  as it does for OP?  I thought Python and transcendental functions were not so tightly defined.

Comment: @njuffa Agree about _should_, etc. except Python is not only implementable via  glibc.  I suspect the functionality seen here is a happy coincidence of 2 transcendental function implementations and not  specified by Python to "work" as seen.  We could go with the the idea that "it behaves that way on all machines I've tested"  spec, yet I prefer a truer spec - hence my _luck_ description.

Comment: @njuffa Does Python specify log, exp, and friends to perform the same across implementations?  Is so, then I agree the "luck" description is not warranted.  Else relying on such code performance is not good.